# TextBox not getting updated from different thread unless MessageBox is shown

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I am trying to execute a command line program and print it output to a textbox in real time:

```
private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\Deps\\ats.exe";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += exeProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

        //MessageBox.Show("Hello"); //Notice this message box before calling WaitForExit                    
        exeProcess.WaitForExit(45000);
    }

    private void exeProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txtOutput.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine + e.Data; }));
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs without error but doesn't print anything to txtOutput
However If i uncomment the message box, the MessageBox is displayed and txtOutput is updated in real time
Now If i click 'OK' to close the MessageBox, txtOutput stops updating again !!

What exactly is going on here? Why is the textBox updated only when i show the MessageBox?

Comment: I suspect that you're not actually getting the output from your console application the way you think you are (my console redirect is a bit rusty).  Put some debugging code in your delegate to output the `e.Data` to the debug window to verify you're actually getting some output.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, i know i am getting output from the console application because as long as the MessageBox is displayed the text box shows the output but as soon as i close the message box the output stops updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem you have here is probably that the `exeProcess.WaitForExit(45000);` is blocking the UI thread.  So the call to `txtOutput.Invoke` posts a message to the window message queue, which is processed by the UI thread.  Since that UI thread is blocked with a wait state, it cannot process those textbox posts.

So what you need to do is wait for the process to exit without blocking the UI thread.  There are several ways you could do this, but one way would be to use the process `Exited` event with a call back.  I don't see enough of your code here to give a full example, but you would want to rewrite something like this:

```
private Process _exeProcess;

private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\Deps\\ats.exe";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    _exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
    _exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += exeProcess_OutputDataReceived;
    _exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();    
    _exeProcess.Exited += ContinueOnYourWay;
}

private void ContinueOnYourWay(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Clean up
    _exeProcess.Dispose();
    _exeProcess = null;

    // More code here
}

private void exeProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtOutput.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtOutput.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine + e.Data; }));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes that works, i'll have to modify the rest of my code a bit, i guess i can also wait like: while (!exeProcess.HasExited)
                            {
                                //Thread.Sleep(500);
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }

Comment: Just as a general rule of thumb, its usually a bad idea to put any kind of wait in an UI event handler (i.e. the UI thread).  That is almost always going to cause your UI to freeze and become unresponsive, and in later versions of windows causes that "This program is not responding" dialog that asks the user if they want to kill it.

Comment: Just saw the edit to your previous comment.  The `Application.DoEvents()` works, it basically yields to `WndProc` to allow it to process a few events.  Personally I wouldn't do this, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i think the Exited event will be a good solution